# Merging array elements based on other arrays elements in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a data structure which the output looks like below:

```
['409597', ['You'], '409597', ['matter'], '409597', ['manager'], '809558', ['metro'], '809558', ['station'], '829258', ['bucket'], '829258', ['water'], '867297'..........]
```

I want to find a way to make this into several arrays which are merged based on the id number. The format I want is as follow:

```
['You','matter','manager'],
['metro','station'],
['bucket','water'],
...........
```

How can I achieve such a list of arrays (in Python) based on the similar ID of the original output I have?

Comment: how did you end up with that wierd data structure in the first place?

Comment: my original was a query of dict format as follow: 
[{'Instant_ID': 409597}, {'Token': 'You'}]
[{'Instant_ID': 409597}, {'Token': 'matter'}]
[{'Instant_ID': 409597}, {'Token': 'manager'}]
[{'Instant_ID': 809558}, {'Token': 'metro'}]
[{'Instant_ID': 809558}, {'Token': 'station'}]
[{'Instant_ID': 829258}, {'Token': 'bucket'}]
[{'Instant_ID': 829258}, {'Token': 'water'}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip_longest` to create key-value pairs of elements and then use `itertools.groupby` to group them together based on the key.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = ['409597', ['You'], '409597', ['matter'], '409597', ['manager'], '809558', ['metro'], '809558', ['station'], '829258', ['bucket'], '829258', ['water']]
>>> [[e[1][0] for e in list(v)] for k,v in groupby(zip_longest(*([iter(l)]*2)), lambda x: x[0])]
[['You', 'matter', 'manager'], ['metro', 'station'], ['bucket', 'water']]
```

Actually, it is slightly easier to work with your original list of dict.

```
ld = [[{'Instant_ID': 409597}, {'Token': 'You'}], [{'Instant_ID': 409597}, {'Token': 'matter'}], [{'Instant_ID': 409597}, {'Token': 'manager'}], [{'Instant_ID': 809558}, {'Token': 'metro'}], [{'Instant_ID': 809558}, {'Token': 'station'}], [{'Instant_ID': 829258}, {'Token': 'bucket'}], [{'Instant_ID': 829258}, {'Token': 'water'}]]
>>> [[e[1]['Token'] for e in v] for k,v in groupby(ld, lambda x: x[0]['Instant_ID'])]
[['You', 'matter', 'manager'], ['metro', 'station'], ['bucket', 'water']]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your source.

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [[{'Instant_ID': 409597}, {'Token': 'You'}], [{'Instant_ID': 409597}, {'Token': 'matter'}], [{'Instant_ID': 409597}, {'Token': 'manager'}], [{'Instant_ID': 809558}, {'Token': 'metro'}], [{'Instant_ID': 809558}, {'Token': 'station'}], [{'Instant_ID': 829258}, {'Token': 'bucket'}], [{'Instant_ID': 829258}, {'Token': 'water'}]]
print([[i[1]["Token"] for i in value] for key, value in groupby(l, lambda x: x[0]["Instant_ID"])])
```

**Output:**

```
[['You', 'matter', 'manager'], ['metro', 'station'], ['bucket', 'water']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using pure Python as well:

```
inList = ['409597', ['You'], '409597', ['matter'], '409597', ['manager'], '809558', ['metro'], '809558', ['station'], '829258', ['bucket'], '829258', ['water']]
#Find all number strings
numbers = sorted(set([inList[i] for i in range(0,len(inList),2)]))
#Create lists based on these number strings
newLists = [[inList[i][0] for i in range(1,len(inList),2) if inList[i-1]==number] for number in numbers]
print(newLists)
```

Output:

```
[['You', 'matter', 'manager'], ['metro', 'station'], ['bucket', 'water']]
```